# get all tweets of a profile using LinqToTwiiter

Tags: c#, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am using LinqToTwitter Api and context for getting all tweets from screen name but i get stuck around 3200 tweets. using max_id and since_id concept as well.
what changes i need to do to get all tweets from a profile using screen name?
Below is my code :`

```
       List<Status> searchResults = new List<Status>();
        try
        {
            var twitterCtx = new TwitterContext(auth);

            int maxNumberToFind = 200;
            ulong sinceID = 1;
            ulong maxID;

            var tweets = (from tweet in twitterCtx.Status
                          where tweet.Type == StatusType.User &&
                              tweet.ScreenName == screenName &&
                              tweet.Count == maxNumberToFind &&
                              tweet.SinceID == sinceID &&
                              tweet.Retweeted==false
                          select tweet).ToList();

            if (tweets.Count > 0)
            { 
                maxID = searchResults.Min(status => status.StatusID) - 1;
                searchResults.AddRange(tweets);
            }

            do
            {
                tweets.Clear();
                tweets = (from tweet in twitterCtx.Status
                          where tweet.Type == StatusType.User &&
                              tweet.ScreenName == screenName &&
                              tweet.Count == maxNumberToFind &&
                              tweet.MaxID == maxID &&
                              tweet.SinceID == sinceID &&
                              tweet.Retweeted == false

                          select tweet).ToList();

                searchResults.AddRange(tweets);


                 maxID = tweets.Min(x => x.StatusID);

            } while (searchResults.Count <= 5000);//tweets.Any()`
     }
         catch (Exception ex) { ex.ToString(); }
        return searchResults;
   }
```

Comment: What's your question/problem exactly?

Comment: i need all tweets . i get stuck around 3200 tweets?

Answer (score 0):

You can not get more than 3200 tweets for a screen name. It is an API restriction :

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline

To get more, you can try web scraping or you can buy data from Gnip.

Bests

Comment: Should i use another API that can give me all tweets?Any Idea?

Comment: If you want historical data, web scraping or gnip.